# What is the equalient of JavaScript's "s.replace(/[^\w]+/g, '-')" in Dart language?

Tags: regex, dart

I am trying to get the following working code in JavaScript also working in Dart.

https://jsfiddle.net/8xyxy8jp/1/

```
var s = "We live, on the # planet    earth";
var results = s.replace(/[^\w]+/g, '-');

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = results;
```

Which gives the output

```
We-live-on-the-planet-earth
```

I have tried this Dart code

```
void main() {
    print( "We live, on the # planet    earth".replaceAll("[^\w]+","-"));
}
```

But the output becomes the same.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Most probably `.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[^\w]+'), '-');`. Or `\W+` should work, too, instead of `[^\w]`.

Comment: `"[^\w]"` is just a string. replaceall expects a regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `replaceAll()` to process the argument as regular expression you need to pass a `RegExp` instance. I usually use `r` as prefix for the regex string to make it a raw string where not interpolation (`$`, `\`, ...) takes place.

```
main() {
  var s = "We live, on the # planet    earth";
  var result = s.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[^\w]+'), '-');
  print(result);
}
```

Try it in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/9429e04bf7f65e76c5c5)